# Catalog ProductList not overriding magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks, preference

I have overridden my catalog product listproduct in etc/di.xml as:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
                    <!--Overrride for Block catalog rewrite product list toolbar -->
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct" />
```

This is my **ListProduct.php** (\Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct.php)

```
namespace Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block\Catalog\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;    

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
public function __construct(
    /*passing all Constructors parameters to the parent class */    
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
     CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    /*passing all Constructors parameters to the parent class */    

    \Tagalys\Tglssearch\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
    $this->catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory = $catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory;
    $this->catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

      parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    ); 
    //$this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
}

protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    print_r('_getProductCollection');die;
    $tagalys = $this->tglssearchHelper->getTagalysSearchData();
     if($tagalys == false) {

        return parent::_getProductCollection();

    } else {

        $searchResult = $tagalys;

        if(empty($searchResult)) {
            return parent::_getProductCollection();
        }

        $collection = $this->_productCollection = $this->catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory->create()
             ->addAttributeToSelect($this->catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
             ->setStore($this->storeManager->getStore())
             ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
             ->addAttributeToFilter( 'entity_id', array( 'in' => $searchResult['results'] ) );  print_r($searchResult);die;

        $orderString = array('CASE e.entity_id');
        foreach($searchResult['results'] as $i => $productId) {
            $orderString[] = 'WHEN '.$productId.' THEN '.$i;
        }
        $orderString[] = 'END';
        $orderString = implode(' ', $orderString);

    $collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr($orderString));

        return $this->_productCollection;

    }
}
```

Why is my `_getProductCollection()` not getting called ?
I get a blank screen when i search for the product.

[image]

Comment: if you implements custom search engine better to use existence interfaces. see \Magento\Framework\Search\SearchEngineInterface

Comment: @Kandy, should i implement the SearchEngineInterface in my custom ListProduct?

Answer (score 0):

Well you get a blank screen because your code stops the method.

By calling the following:

```
print_r('_getProductCollection');die;
```

You simply stop the process of getting the collection.

**That shows that your `_getProductCollection` is properly getting called.**

Comment: yes i had purposefully put print_r in order to check if method is getting called, but not even ''_getProductCollection'' under print_r is getting printed . Even if i remove the print_r() i get a blank

Comment: @SachinS well debugging using simple `print_r` will not work all the time. The fact that you're adding `die()` and the product list page stops working shows that your method is properly getting called. I suggest you used xDebug to debug your code you will avoid issues like this

Comment: Raphael, i had removed all die statements in the function before, i was still getting blank page...

Comment: .i also get in system.xml LAYOUT_frontend_STORE1_3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e and handles : Please correct the XML data and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to complete `</config>` tag inside your di.xml file,

**etc/di.xml** file, add below code inside your **di.xml** file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
                    <!--Overrride for Block catalog rewrite product list toolbar -->
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Tagalys\Tglssearch\Block\Catalog\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

Remove var folder and check your problem are solved.

Comment: <config> is already closed Rakesh, i just took a part of the file code and posted

Comment: in your di.xml in above code its not closed. Have you check using remove var folder